# Printing pattern of "C" character

Tags: command-line, text-processing

I would like to print pattern of Cys residue from each line given in file.tsv. file.tsv has two coloumns as sequenceID and Sequence. from the second column sequence first character "C" should be printed as C, if the next immediate residue is not C then the code should print C#. # should occur only one time for n number of various amino acid occurrence.

So when in Column if "C" is followed by another character I would like to print # after "C". so if sequence column has value DCFRCGHCC then it should print in the third column  C#C#CC.

Example input:

```
c32_g1_i1_ 3GQKAKLKVPVFFLHRRGSICSSFYLMFSFEIKKK*TSKN*CFVCVRVRNRERAGVKCAHVYCPMFNGTQTH*IIISSLNS
c32_g1_i1_ 6AV*TADDDLVRLCSIEHGTIHMCTLYTCCTLTVTHTYTHKTLIFACLFFFNFKGEHQIERAANRTSSM*KKHRNF*LGLLAX
```

The output should be three columns: sequenceID, Sequence, Cys pattern

```
c32_g1_i1_3,GQKAKLKVPVFFLHRRGSICSSFYLMFSFEIKKK*TSKN*CFVCVRVRNRERAGVKCAHVYCPMFNGTQTH*IIISSLNS,C#C#C#C#C
c32_g1_i1_6,AV*TADDDLVRLCSIEHGTIHMCTLYTCCTLTVTHTYTHKTLIFACLFFFNFKGEHQIERAANRTSSM*KKHRNF*LGLLAX,C#C#CC#C
```

Comment: You can't expect most of us to be biologists or to deal smoothly with patterns of Cys, fasta sequences etc. Please rephrase the question so that knowing biology to that extent is not a must to understand it.

Comment: How you're arriving at `C#C#C#C#C` and `C#C#CC#C` is not entirely clear. Are you inserting a `#` when the next character *isn't* a `C`?

Comment: As stated this question is a bad fit here, we a linux computer enthusiasts not biologists (well some may be) How ever you can ask at Biology stackexchange ( theres a stack for everything these days :) ) http://biology.stackexchange.com/

Comment: So when in line if "C" is followed by another character I would like to print # after "C". so if line is DCFRCGHCC then it should have C#C#CC.  many thanks for replying so quick

Comment: So take the 2nd string, print only the Cs, separate them with a `#` if not immediately followed by another C. Print the output on the same line, after the already occurring 2 fields, comma separating all 3 fields. Is that correct?

Comment: yes. exactly as you mentioned

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The first one-liner / full script parse and convert the file format described in the question; the second full script parses and converts a FASTA file format.

---

#### #1

Golfed one-liner:

```
perl -lane 'my $s;my @m=$F[1]=~/C.?/g;foreach(@m){$_ eq"CC"?$s.="C":$s.="C#"}push(@F,$s);print(join(",",@F))' infile
```

Expanded full script:

```perl
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

@ARGV == 1 || die("Usage: <command> <input_file>\n");

open(my $in, $ARGV[0]) || die("Could not open input file \"$ARGV[0]\": $!\n");

while(<$in>) {
    my $string;
    my @fields = split(" ");
    my @matches = $fields[1] =~ /C.?/g;
    foreach(@matches) {
        $_ eq "CC" ? $string .= "C" : $string .= "C#"
    }
    push(@fields, $string);
    print(join(",", @fields) . "\n")
}

close($in);

exit
```

Explanation:

- The input file is processed line by line;
- Each line is splitted into two strings, the part before the space and the part after the space;
- Each substring made of a "C" character optionally followed by another character (optionally to catch also a "C" character at the end of the string) in the second string is evaluated, and if the character following the "C" is a "C", "C" is appended to the end of a custom temporary string; otherwise "C#" is appended at the end of the custom temporary string;
- The first, second and custom temporary string are printed, comma-separated, followed by a newline;

Sample output:

```
% cat infile
c32_g1_i1_3 GQKAKLKVPVFFLHRRGSICSSFYLMFSFEIKKK*TSKN*CFVCVRVRNRERAGVKCAHVYCPMFNGTQTH*IIISSLNS
c32_g1_i1_6 AV*TADDDLVRLCSIEHGTIHMCTLYTCCTLTVTHTYTHKTLIFACLFFFNFKGEHQIERAANRTSSM*KKHRNF*LGLLAX
% perl -ne 'my $s;my @f=split(" ");my @m=$f[1]=~/C.?/g;foreach(@m){$_ eq"CC"?$s.="C":$s.="C#"}push(@f,$s);print(join(",",@f)."\n")' infile
c32_g1_i1_3,GQKAKLKVPVFFLHRRGSICSSFYLMFSFEIKKK*TSKN*CFVCVRVRNRERAGVKCAHVYCPMFNGTQTH*IIISSLNS,C#C#C#C#C#
c32_g1_i1_6,AV*TADDDLVRLCSIEHGTIHMCTLYTCCTLTVTHTYTHKTLIFACLFFFNFKGEHQIERAANRTSSM*KKHRNF*LGLLAX,C#C#CC#C#
```

---

#### #2

Expanded full version:

```perl
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

@ARGV == 1 || die("Usage: <command> <input_file>\n");

open(my $in, $ARGV[0]) || die("Could not open input file \"$ARGV[0]\": $!\n");
open(my $tmp, "+>", "tmpfile") || die("Could not create temporary file \"tmpfile\": $!\n");

select($tmp);

while(<$in>) {
    if(/^>/) {
        s/$/ /
    }
    if(my $next = <$in>) {
        if($next !~ /^>/) {
            chomp
        }
        print;
        seek($in, -length($next), 1)
    }
    else {
        print
    }
}

close($in);

seek($tmp, 0, 0);

select(STDOUT);

while(<$tmp>) {
    my $string;
    my @fields = split(/ (?!.* )|\n/);
    my @matches = $fields[1] =~ /C.?/g;
    foreach(@matches) {
        $_ eq "CC" ? $string .= "C" : $string .= "C#"
    }
    push(@fields, $string);
    print(join(",", @fields) . "\n")
}

close($tmp);

unlink("tmpfile");

exit
```

Explanation:

- The input file is processed line by line;
- If the current line starts with a `>` character, a space is appended to the line; if a following line exists and doesn't start with a `>` character, the newline character is stripped from the current line; the current line is printed to a temporary file;
- The temporary file is processed line by line;
- Each line is splitted into two strings, the part before the last space and the part after the last space;
- Each substring made of a "C" character optionally followed by another character (optionally to catch also a "C" character at the end of the string) in the second string is evaluated, and if the character following the "C" is a "C", "C" is appended to the end of a custom temporary string; otherwise "C#" is appended at the end of the custom temporary string;
- The first, second and custom temporary string are printed, comma-separated, followed by a newline;
- The temporary file is removed;

Sample output:

```
% cat infile 
>c32_g1_i1_
3GQKAKLKVPVFFLHRRGSICSSFYLMFSFEIKKK*TSKN*CFVCVRVRNRERAGVKCAHVYCPMFNGTQTH*IIISSLNS
3GQKAKLKVPVFFLHRRGSICSSFYLMFSFEIKKK*TSKN*CFVCVRVRNRERAGVKCAHVYCPMFNGTQTH*IIISSLNS
>c32_g1_i1_
6AV*TADDDLVRLCSIEHGTIHMCTLYTCCTLTVTHTYTHKTLIFACLFFFNFKGEHQIERAANRTSSM*KKHRNF*LGLLAX
6AV*TADDDLVRLCSIEHGTIHMCTLYTCCTLTVTHTYTHKTLIFACLFFFNFKGEHQIERAANRTSSM*KKHRNF*LGLLAX
% perl script.pl infile 
>c32_g1_i1_,3GQKAKLKVPVFFLHRRGSICSSFYLMFSFEIKKK*TSKN*CFVCVRVRNRERAGVKCAHVYCPMFNGTQTH*IIISSLNS3GQKAKLKVPVFFLHRRGSICSSFYLMFSFEIKKK*TSKN*CFVCVRVRNRERAGVKCAHVYCPMFNGTQTH*IIISSLNS,C#C#C#C#C#C#C#C#C#C#
>c32_g1_i1_,6AV*TADDDLVRLCSIEHGTIHMCTLYTCCTLTVTHTYTHKTLIFACLFFFNFKGEHQIERAANRTSSM*KKHRNF*LGLLAX6AV*TADDDLVRLCSIEHGTIHMCTLYTCCTLTVTHTYTHKTLIFACLFFFNFKGEHQIERAANRTSSM*KKHRNF*LGLLAX,C#C#CC#C#C#C#CC#C#
```

Comment: This code works perfectly fine. And many thanks for your detailed explaination

Comment: @Trupti You're welcome, although I don't think it was actually explained well; I've added an explanation of the script, if you want to double-check whether it actually does exactly what you want.

Comment: but it also allowed me to understand how the while loop worked

Comment: @Trupti Apparently the real format of your input file is the one currently shown in your question; can you confirm that? If so I'll have to change my answer.

Comment: @kos Yeah, sorry about that. The Fasta format includes `>seqname` and Oli, very understandably, assumed the `>` was meant for quoting. Since the OP mentions Fasta sequences, that should be the right format.

Comment: @Kos its totally fine. There is easy way to change the fasta formate into csv or text. And I am very happy with the code.

Comment: @Trupti Ok; I rolled back your question to the "wrong" version, since this answer works for you, so that they don't mismatch, mostly for future readers

Comment: @terdon Thanks. I rolled back the question to the "wrong" version since my answer (and steeldriver's answer, which I'm flagging for undeletion) work for OP; maybe you want to undelete yours as well?

Comment: @kos please don't. The OP clearly stated that they have files in [FASTA format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FASTA_format) and that's what was in the original question. Your answer works for both formats since the OP's example doesn't have any `C`s in the sequence names.

Comment: @terdon The problem is that as far as I understand that format can include multiple lines after each `>` header; my and steeldriver's solution would break in that case. I think that at least the input format should be explicitly defined as having always a single line after each header, otherwise it might generate confusion.

Comment: @kos yes, the format can have multiple lines per header but also often, as in the OP's example, doesn't. What is absolutely required is the `>foo\n` to define a header. If you take that away, it's not fasta. The OP asked for fasta and showed fasta in their original question, therefore editing it to a completely different format seems like bad form. Look at the source of the original question before the edits.

Comment: @terdon No, by the way the answer(s) are completely broken by that edit (regardless of one or more lines after the header). I see your point in not editing the question, however it's also not nice to have a broken undeletable accepted answer. Let's just ask OP what they want to do.

Comment: @Trupti Originally you aked about FASTA format; would you consider rolling back your question to [this](http://askubuntu.com/revisions/682460/3) revision so that the answer(s) could match it? If not please unaccept my answer, so that I can't delete it, because as it currently stands it's broken and doesn't answer the question.

Comment: @kos  I apologise for not being able to reply on time. It turned out that the formate you made is more useful for my further analysis. And I would like to  have your answer.  Is it possible for you to change the question back to the way you edited. meaning as shown in your answer input. Many thanks

Comment: @Trupti Ok! I've added back the initial space between the header and the sequence. However I had some time yesterday and since it wasn't clear whether I should have edited my answer or not I ended up creating a script which converts an actual FASTA file to that format regardless, so at this point I'll add it to my answer later

Comment: Since I know nothing about these things I made the assumption that in case of a multiline sequence the lines should have been merged first in order to obtain a single long sequence like in the example, as as far as I understand the sequence following the header is splitted only for the ease of not having extremely long lines in the file

Comment: Yes, thats true. extremely long lines are the reasons behind.
Thank you so much. I would really appreciate if you can share that answer as well. As I can learn something.

Comment: @Trupti Done, check out the update. It was challenging I have to say :) the downside is that the input file will be processed twice, and that a copy of the file is made during the execution; this might not be optimal if your file is *huge*, however for the rest it should be fine

Comment: @kos thank you again. Just tested on my data. works exactly the way it should. And I really appreciate your efforts.

Comment: @Trupti Nah I enjoy these things, glad to hear that it works, that it helped and that it can be useful :)

Comment: Hello! is there a way to print number of residues between 'C' instead of #? meaning instead of C#C#CC#, C5C4CC12 based on how many characters between two 'C' character

Answer (score 0):

Here's an `awk` version that might work for you

```
awk '{OFS=","; $3=$2; sub(/[^C]+/,"",$3); gsub(/[^C]+/,"#",$3); print}' file
```

It just duplicates the second field, then strips any non-empty initial sequence of non-C characters in the duplicate, then replaces each remaining sequence of non-C characters in it with `#`.

Comment: This also works great! thank you for explaining another way to work

Comment: This was clever, but apparently the real format of the input file is the one currently shown in the question, so apparently this answer has been invalidated as well.