# printing distances of desired character based on occurance

Tags: command-line, text-processing, perl, awk

This is an extension of my previous question ([Printing pattern of "C" character](https://askubuntu.com/questions/682460/printing-pattern-of-c-character)).

I would like to print "C" character from "text" column given in file.csv. The file.csv has two coloumns as ID and text.

I need to edit the distances in between as well as starting of the character such as following

So when in Column "text", printing the distance between two C characters such as, if "text" column has value DCFRCGHCCRF then it should print in the third column 1C2C2CC2

example input

```
c32_g1_i1_3,SCIPKHEECTNDKHNCCRKGLFKLKCQCSTFDDESGQPTERCACGRPMGHQAIETGLNIFRGLFKGKKKNKKTKG
c32_g1_i1_6,ACAERKKKCTKDDDCSCCGKWDKCSCNWPGREGCFCMRGMMATRLWKMAKC
```

Example output

```
c32_g1_i1_3,SCIPKHEECTNDKHNCCRKGLFKLKCQCSTFDDESGQPTERCACGRPMGHQAIETGLNIFRGLFKGKKKNKKTKG,1c6c6cc8c1c13c1c31
c32_g1_i1_6,ACAERKKKCTKDDDCSCCGKWDKCSCNWPGREGCFCMRGMMATRLWKMAKC,1c6c5c1cc5c1c7c1c14c0
```

Answer (score 1):

How about something like this

```
perl -F, -alne '
  my @a = split "C", @F[1]; 
  my @b = (map { $_ ? length $_ : "" } @a); 
  print join ",", (@F, join "c", @b)
' file.csv 
c32_g1_i1_3,SCIPKHEECTNDKHNCCRKGLFKLKCQCSTFDDESGQPTERCACGRPMGHQAIETGLNIFRGLFKGKKKNKKTKG,1c6c6cc8c1c13c1c31
c32_g1_i1_6,ACAERKKKCTKDDDCSCCGKWDKCSCNWPGREGCFCMRGMMATRLWKMAKC,1c6c5c1cc5c1c7c1c14
```

Or more compactly

```
perl -F, -alne '
  print join ",", (@F, join "c", (map { $_ ? length $_ : "" } split "C", @F[1]))
' file.csv
```

---

To get the desired behavior when there is a trailing `C` in the input, it is necessary to modify the `split` command with an explicit `LIMIT` parameter as noted - somewhat opaquely - in the [split() perldoc](http://perldoc.perl.org/5.8.9/functions/split.html) :

> Empty trailing fields, on the other hand, are produced when there is a
>   match at the end of the string (**and when LIMIT is given and is not 0**),
>   regardless of the length of the match.

So the expression becomes

```
$ perl -F, -alne '
  print join ",", (@F, join "c", (map { $_ ? length $_ : "" } split "C", @F[1], -1))
' file.csv
c32_g1_i1_3,SCIPKHEECTNDKHNCCRKGLFKLKCQCSTFDDESGQPTERCACGRPMGHQAIETGLNIFRGLFKGKKKNKKTKG,1c6c6cc8c1c13c1c31
c32_g1_i1_6,ACAERKKKCTKDDDCSCCGKWDKCSCNWPGREGCFCMRGMMATRLWKMAKC,1c6c5c1cc5c1c7c1c14c
```

---

(inspiration for the `map` taken from [the quikest [sic] way to remove empty array elements](http://www.tek-tips.com/viewthread.cfm?qid=68474))

Comment: Many thanks, this works perfectly fine, However would you please guide me on how to write this as perl program instead of one liner I would really appreciate it.

Comment: @Trupti I'm not the best at "real" perl scripts - see if this helps [How can I convert Perl one-liners into complete scripts?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2822525/how-can-i-convert-perl-one-liners-into-complete-scripts) especially the `-MO=Deparse` trick

Comment: there is one issue with the code :( it does not print the last "C" 
example
c51973_g1_i2_3,YIHFNSSQKCQCKGQSLLPVDCQQLLIVTNFVRSALCC,9c1c9c14
c54038_g1_i1_16,SCNTGCCNVDFPINKIFNKRGVASILGLIMVTKMQTMNILKCQCFVVIC,1c3cc34c1c4

Comment: @Trupti please see updated answer: the trick seems to be to add an explicit `-1` limit parameter to the `split`